# The script doesn't exist or is invalid

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this code on stack overflow and I am trying to use it to open Internet Explorer with a link in the email that comes from a specific address (I created a rule for this).

When I try to run it I receive the following error: "The script doesn't exist or is invalid.". I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010.

```
Sub LaunchURL(itm As MailItem)

    Dim bodyString As String
    Dim bodyStringSplitLine
    Dim bodyStringSplitWord
    Dim splitLine
    Dim splitWord

    bodyString = itm.Body
    bodyStringSplitLine = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)

    For Each splitLine In bodyStringSplitLine
        bodyStringSplitWord = Split(splitLine, " ")

        For Each splitWord In bodyStringSplitWord
            If Left(splitWord, 7) = "http://" Then
               Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" & " " & splitWord)

            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set itm = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub test()
    Dim currItem As MailItem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    LaunchURL currItem
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this code out, and found no problem. IE window came up. Please make sure your project name is valid. Also, try removing the rule, then renaming the project, then adding the rule back in. Also, from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15153b16-eb30-4290-9ef0-bac13a3906cb/starting-a-macro-using-outlook-rule: "CAUTION: Using this technique has been known to result in corrupt VBA code. Be sure to export your code modules or back up the VBAProject.otm file."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the script is wrong. You try to open each word from the message body in the web browser. You need to find a real URL instead.

You need to use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items to get a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Then you can look for the `<a href=` tags. Only in that case you can get the URL and run it in the browser.

Also, as a workaround, you may consider using the Word object model. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body. Then you can use the [Hyperlinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837239(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Document class which returns a Hyperlinks collection that represents all the hyperlinks in the specified document. For example:

```
For Each aHyperlink In document.Hyperlinks 
   If InStr(LCase(aHyperlink.Address), "microsoft") <> 0 Then  
     MsgBox aHyperlink.Name 
   End If 
Next aHyperlink
```

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

There is no need to specify the path to the IE on the machine. For example, you can use the following code instead:

> Shell (splitWord)

The default web browser will be opened. Moreover, the path to the IE can be wrong and depend on the machine (x86 or x64).

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article helpful.